# Install4j Execution throws null pointer exception only in windows

Tags: nullpointerexception, install4j

**This issue doesn't stop the installation but the final installation.log has the sequence of this NULL POINTER exception.**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.loadIconNoCache(GUIHelper.java:236)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.loadIcon(GUIHelper.java:224)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.withIcon(GUIHelper.java:209)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.groups.LayoutManagerGroup.createWrapperContent(LayoutManagerGroup.java:211)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.groups.LayoutManagerGroup.wrap(LayoutManagerGroup.java:201)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.buildPanel(FormPanel.java:447)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.setupComponent(FormPanel.java:310)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.init(FormPanel.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.FormPanel.<init>(FormPanel.java:55)
```

Comment: What version of install4j do you use? Have you tried with the current version?

Comment: install4j Multi-Platform Edition 7.0.12 (build 7368) for mac. Is this is a known issue in this version?

Comment: No, but there have been some related changes since. Can you try with 8.0.5?